# Read files in a directory matching a particular pattern through MapReduce and output the names of the individual files

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to read the files in a directory, the path to which is specified as arguments to the MapReduce program. The aim is to perform some computation, on each file (say the number of occurrences of a  particular word). Also the name of the file must match a pattern(say a .java file). The output the program is the name of the file together with the value of the computation.

Till now I have been able to implement a very basic Map program which reads the contents of the directory without any specific pattern and outputs the name of the file and a constant number. The mapper code looks something like this

```
 public class CCMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable>{
    private static IntWritable complexityCount = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text result = new Text();

    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {

        String fileName = ((FileSplit) context.getInputSplit()).getPath().getName();
        result.set(filePathString);
        context.write(result, complexityCount);

    }
 }
```

The input directory has 3 files - file1, file2, file3 . But the output of this program looks something like this

```
file1.txt   1
file1.txt   1
file1.txt   1
file1.txt   1
file1.txt   1
file1.txt   1
file1.txt   1
file2.txt   1
file2.txt   1
file2.txt   1
file2.txt   1
file3.txt   1
```

How do I get the program to output one occurrences for each file. Also is there a way to read one file at a time, perform the computation on that file and output the name of the file and the result? How do I modify the value of the InputSplit to match the size of each particular file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand your code is reading each file for its contents.
File1 must have 7 lines, hence the key value pair is "File1.txt 1" once for each line.
similarly File2.txt must have 4 lines and File3.txt 1 line.

To output one occurrence of each file, you will have to write code in reduce function to sum up the values on basis of keys.

```
  public static class Reduce extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {

@Override
public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
  int sum = 0;
  for (IntWritable value : values) {
    sum += value.get();
  }

  context.write(key, new IntWritable(sum));
}
```

}